Select multiple columns from array, multiple times
Hi I have the following setup:
from scipy
def _bootstrap_resample(sample, n_resamples=None, random_state=None):
    """Bootstrap resample the sample."""
    n = sample.shape[-1]

    # bootstrap - each row is a random resample of original observations
    i = rng_integers(random_state, 0, n, (n_resamples, n))

    resamples = sample[..., i]
    return resamples

in my case:
sample:
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]]

i:
[[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3]]

what i want:
[[[ 0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1]
  [10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11]]

 [[ 2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3]
  [12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13]]]

i.e. multiple rows of i are just supposed to say which columns to take and create new examples. The provided code:
resamples = sample[..., i]

does not do that unfortunately and produces
[[[ 0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1]
  [ 2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3]]

 [[10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11]
  [12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13]]]

How can I obtain what I want here?

Btw the above function works great if sample is 1-D array

For clarity, could you give the expected output if sample = np.arange(20).reshape((2, -1))+100?

Also, do you always start from 2D arrays? How would it generalize?

So the general case is we have n example arrays of some shape. we pack them into sample so that last dimension is example number so shape is (a,b,c,n) for 3 dimensional examples of shape (a,b,c). now we draw indices i of shape (n_resamples, col_numbers)
col_numbers are from range(n) and they just select particular example, but we want to do that n_resamples times.

In other words what i want we could get with:
result = np.array([sample[..., i_row] for i_row in i])
but question is if there is a way to do that without for loop so that it matches the logic in scipy.

This function is supposed to perform resampling, so question is if i supplied sample wrong? Is this bug?

OK, so IIUC, you might want np.moveaxis(sample[..., i], -2, 0) to go from (a, b, c) to (n, a, b, c).

The exact expected logic is not fully clear, but you might want to moveaxis:
resamples = np.moveaxis(sample[..., i], -2, 0)

Output:
array([[[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
        [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11]],

       [[ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3],
        [12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13]]])

generalization
If you have sample of shape (a, b, c, ..., z) and i of shape (n, z), this will give you an output of shape (n, a, b, c, ..., z).
Example:
sample = np.arange(3*4*5*10).reshape((3, 4, 5, -1))+100
# shape: (3, 4, 5, 10)

n = sample.shape[-1]
# 10

n_resamples = 20
# bootstrap - each row is a random resample of original observations
rng = np.random.default_rng()
i = rng.integers(0, n, (n_resamples, n))
# shape: (20, 10)

resamples = np.moveaxis(sample[..., i], -2, 0)
# shape: (20, 3, 4, 5, 10)


Thank you for your help. It helped me to understand what was going on with resamples. In the end the issue seems to be known:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/20850
Also the answer on how to supply input to bootstrap is suggested there by mdhaber
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/20850#issuecomment-2143271334
